# Cohomology ring of flag variety

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

So I was concerned with one of Hatcher's remarks. When he is computing the cohomology ring of the Grasmannian he makes a short aside by saying that $H^\ast(F_n(\mathbb{C}^k);\mathbb{Z})$ is equal to the free module generated by $x_1^{j_1}\cdots x_n^{j_n}$ where $j_i\leq k-i$. In other words this can be realized as just $\mathbb{Z}[z_1]/(z_1^{k})\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathbb{Z}[z_n]/(z_n^{k-n+1})$. But Hatcher also claims that the cohomology ring can be rewritten as $\mathbb{Z}[z_1,...,z_n]/(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)$, where $\sigma_i$ are the symmetric polynomials. Are these two spaces equivalent or have I misunderstood something. I would really appreciate some feedback. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Note that the first half can be seen from page 436.

Comment: Sorry, where does Hatcher claim the cohomology ring can be rewritten as $\mathbb{Z}[z_1, \dots, z_n]/(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n)$?

Comment: That's actually one of the problems in that section. I just don't see why the two are actually equivalent, and I am just seeing if someone can confirm that the two spaces are actually isomorphic. I don't need the actual isomorphism though.

Comment: It's nontrivial that these are the same. Also just because we can write it in terms of monomials in that way doesn't imply that the ring structure is so simplistic in terms of this natural basis. Say we have $n=k=3$. Then $x_2^2=-x_1^2-x_1x_2$.

Comment: Note that your first expression is for any $k \geq n$, whereas the second expression is only for $k = n$. Furthermore, your first expression is incorrect as written; all the exponents should increase by $1$.

Comment: @Michael no, the part with the exponents is right. For $n=3$ the top class is $x_1^2x_2$.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant it should be $\mathbb{Z}[z_1]/(z_1^k)$ etc.

Comment: I have corrected it.